# AppScript creates HTML table but doesn't format table subheaders

Tags: html, css, google-apps-script

I have cobbled together an Appscript which is supposed to do the following:

1. Create two collapsible containers (not pictured below because this part works fine).
2. In each container is a table with information pulled from google sheets.
3. Each table has top row headers, and subheadings.
4. The subheadings are defined in the google sheet by the text being wrapped in [ ].

The app script works fine... other than the formatting of the subheadings.    Below is a table of the current result.

I am unable to get the color of the subheading font to change and the shading seems to just follow the row above it.
[image: CURRENT RESULT]

```
function convertGrantsAndLoansTableToHtml() {
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var grantsSheetName = "Grants"; // Modify this to match the Grants sheet name
var loansSheetName = "Loans"; // Modify this to match the Loans sheet name

var grantsSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(grantsSheetName);
var loansSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(loansSheetName);

var grantsRange = grantsSheet.getDataRange();
var loansRange = loansSheet.getDataRange();

var grantsData = grantsRange.getValues();
var loansData = loansRange.getValues();

var html = '<style> \
.expandable-section { margin-bottom: 10px; } \
.expandable-section input[type="checkbox"] { display: none; } \
.expandable-section label { \
display: block; \
cursor: pointer; \
font-family: "Calibri", sans-serif; /* Change the font here */ \
font-weight: bold; \
font-size: 20px; \
color: #FCFCFC; \
background-color: #84B83F; \
padding: 4px 6px; \
border-radius: 3px; \
} \
.expandable-section input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label { \
background-color: #84B83F; \
color: #FCFCFC; \
} \
.expandable-section-content { \
display: none; \
} \
.expandable-section input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ .expandable-section-content { \
display: block; \
margin-top: 5px; \
} \
table { \
border-collapse: collapse; \
font-size: medium; \
width: 100%; \
font-family: "Calibri", sans-serif; /* Change the font here */ \
} \
th, td { \
border: 1px solid black; \
padding: 8px; \
} \
th { \
font-weight: bold; \
font-size: larger; \
text-align: left; \
color: #F37525; \
} \
th.section-header { \
font-size: smaller; \
text-align: center; \
color: #84B83F; \
} \
th:first-child, td:first-child { \
font-weight: bold; \
} \
tr:not(.section-header):nth-child(even) { \
background-color: #E4E4E4; \
} \
</style>';

html += '<div class="expandable-section">';
html += '<input type="checkbox" id="grantsToggle">';
html += '<label for="grantsToggle">Grants Form Fields</label>';

html += '<div class="expandable-section-content">';
html += '<table>';

for (var i = 0; i < grantsData.length; i++) {
html += '<tr>';

for (var j = 0; j < grantsData[i].length; j++) {
var cellValue = grantsData[i][j];
var isHeaderRow = (i === 0);
var isLeftColumn = (j === 0);

if (isHeaderRow) {
if (cellValue.startsWith('[') && cellValue.endsWith(']')) {
html += '<th class="section-header">' + cellValue.substring(1, cellValue.length - 1) + '</th>';
} else {
html += '<th>' + cellValue + '</th>';
}
} else if (cellValue.startsWith('[') && cellValue.endsWith(']')) {
html += '<tr><th colspan="' + grantsData[i].length + '">' + cellValue.substring(1, cellValue.length - 1) + '</th></tr>';
break; // Skip the remaining cells in this row
} else {
if (isLeftColumn) {
html += '<td><b>' + cellValue + '</b></td>';
} else {
html += '<td>' + cellValue + '</td>';
}
}
}

html += '</tr>';
}

html += '</table>';
html += '</div>'; // End of expandable-section-content
html += '</div>'; // End of expandable-section

html += '<div class="expandable-section">';
html += '<input type="checkbox" id="loansToggle">';
html += '<label for="loansToggle">Loans Form Fields</label>';

html += '<div class="expandable-section-content">';
html += '<table>';

for (var i = 0; i < loansData.length; i++) {
html += '<tr>';

for (var j = 0; j < loansData[i].length; j++) {
var cellValue = loansData[i][j];
var isHeaderRow = (i === 0);
var isLeftColumn = (j === 0);

if (isHeaderRow) {
if (cellValue.startsWith('[') && cellValue.endsWith(']')) {
html += '<th class="section-header">' + cellValue.substring(1, cellValue.length - 1) + '</th>';
} else {
html += '<th>' + cellValue + '</th>';
}
} else if (cellValue.startsWith('[') && cellValue.endsWith(']')) {
html += '<tr><th colspan="' + loansData[i].length + '">' + cellValue.substring(1, cellValue.length - 1) + '</th></tr>';
break; // Skip the remaining cells in this row
} else {
if (isLeftColumn) {
html += '<td><b>' + cellValue + '</b></td>';
} else {
html += '<td>' + cellValue + '</td>';
}
}
}

html += '</tr>';
}

html += '</table>';
html += '</div>'; // End of expandable-section-content
html += '</div>'; // End of expandable-section


var date = new Date();
var dateString = date.toLocaleDateString().replace(/\//g, '-');
var timeString = date.toLocaleTimeString().replace(/:/g, '-');
var fileName = "output_" + dateString + "_" + timeString + ".html";
var folderName = "Output"; // Name of the folder where the file will be saved
var parentFolder = DriveApp.getRootFolder();
var folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(folderName);

if (folders.hasNext()) {
parentFolder = folders.next();
} else {
parentFolder = parentFolder.createFolder(folderName);
}

var file = parentFolder.createFile(fileName, html, "text/html");
Logger.log('File created: ' + file.getUrl());
```

Comment: Can you share a minimum reproducible example.(https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Please share at least a dummy sheet file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Follow the Row Banding and Change the Font Color:

I have tested here on my end. I can see that the reason why there is duplication on the color of the row bonding is because of the extra time that you are calling . I also manage to add something that will change the font.

> ***NOTE**: Due to the limited information about your target result. It might be that the code might not perfectly fit your  whole project you can use this as a reference to get the desired output.*

### Sample Code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < grantsData.length; i++) {
html += '<tr>';

for (var j = 0; j < grantsData[i].length; j++) {
var cellValue = grantsData[i][j];
var isHeaderRow = (i === 0);
var isLeftColumn = (j === 0);

if (isHeaderRow) {
if (cellValue.startsWith('[') && cellValue.endsWith(']')) {
html += '<th class="section-header">' + cellValue.substring(1, cellValue.length - 1) + '</th>';
} else {
html += '<th>' + cellValue + '</th>';
}
} else if (cellValue.startsWith('[') && cellValue.endsWith(']')) {
html += '<td colspan="' + grantsData[i].length + '" style="color: blue;">' + cellValue.substring(1, cellValue.length - 1) + '</td>';//removed extra <tr> and added style code
break;
} else {
if (isLeftColumn) {
html += '<td><b>' + cellValue + '</b></td>';
} else {
html += '<td>' + cellValue + '</td>';
}
}
}

html += '</tr>';
}
```

### Result:

Change "Orange" to "Blue" font. Blue fonts are your supposed sub-headers.
[image]

### Reference:

[Table Tags](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_table.asp)